# vsnprintf problems with variable arguments

Tags: c++, xcode

The following code will give the expected result on Visual Studio 2012 but not on XCode 5.0 . What do I miss?

```
static std::string format(const std::string fmt, ...)
{
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, fmt);
    int size=vsnprintf(0, 0, fmt.c_str(), vl);

    if(size<1)
        return std::string();


    char szBuf[256];

    vsnprintf(szBuf, 256, fmt.c_str(), vl);

    return szBuf;
}
```

The call:

```
for(int no=1;no<10;no++)
{
    std::string strPath=format("entry%02d.txt",no);
}
```

will result in correct "entry01.txt" on Windows but it is "entry1852125044.txt" on OSX with XCode.

The above code is shorten to focus on the problem. That is the reason for looking odd (asking for size and not use it). Also I need to process format strings.

Comment: Why do that extra step to get the size if you still are going to use a fixed-size buffer? Also, why not simply use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)? If you want to allocate dynamically, you might want to see e.g. the example in [this Linux manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/vsnprintf) (and you can easily change the C dynamic handling with `std::string`).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg It is only part of the code to keep it focused on the problem. That is the reason for looking odd. std::istringstream cannot process format strings.

Comment: Well, with C++ streams you use the normal [manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) instead of formatting codes. Yes, it's more to write, but it's also much safer.

Comment: Oh and by the way, there's also the [Boost format library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) if you're already using Boost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over the `va_list` twice, once for each call to `vsnprintf`. You need to bracket each iteration in a `va_start/va_end` pair:

```
//...
va_start(vl, fmt);
int size=vsnprintf(0, 0, fmt.c_str(), vl);
va_end(v1);

//...

va_start(vl, fmt);
vsnprintf(szBuf, 256, fmt.c_str(), vl);
va_end(vl);
```

Comment: That's it! I found that during building the sample for the question too, but I was not sure if that was the real problem. Wonder why VS do not care about that. Thnx!

Comment: @MartinSchlott How `va_list` and its associated functions are implemented is *implementation defined*, so it most likely will differ between compilers, and maybe even on the same compiler depending on platform or even version.